# Why doesn't asyncio.TaskGroup wait for the queue to finish?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Im python asyncio newbie,
In my code, `total_slept_for` value is 0.
I want to calculate the total time it takes for all the values inside the queue to finish.

Any help or idea??
Thanks.

This is my code:
**python version : 3.11.4**

```
import asyncio
import random
import time


async def worker(name, queue):
    while True:
        # queue.get()
        try:
            sleep_for = queue.get_nowait()
        except asyncio.QueueEmpty:
            break
        print(f"sleep_for : {sleep_for}")

        await asyncio.sleep(sleep_for)

        # Notify the queue work item has been processed
        queue.task_done()

        print(f"{name} has slept for {sleep_for:.2f} seconds")


async def main():
    # Create Quere
    q = asyncio.Queue()

    total_sleep_time = 0
    for _ in range(20):
        sleep_for = random.uniform(0.05, 1.0)
        total_sleep_time += sleep_for
        q.put_nowait(sleep_for)

    # Create 3 workers
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        for idx in range(3):
            tg.create_task(worker(f"worker-{idx}", q))

    # Calc total running time
    started_at = time.monotonic()
    # Waiting finish Queue
    await q.join()
    print(time.monotonic())
    total_slept_for = time.monotonic() - started_at

    print("====")
    print(f"3 workers slept in parallel for {total_slept_for:.2f} seconds")
    print(f"total expected sleep time: {total_sleep_time:.2f} seconds")


asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:` waits for the task group to finish. That means all the tasks are *already done sleeping* by the time you start timing.

You need to put the timing code and `await q.join()` *inside* the `async with`.

Comment: Why `await q.join()` code put inside the `async with`??
Is it different inside and outside?

Comment: @yeov: Well, if you put it outside the `async with` and put the timing code inside, then you would start timing, end timing, and not time anything.